# Can a column from a datagrid be formatted to ToShortDateString?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, datagrid, date-format

I have a column in a datagrid that displays the date like 2014-04-21 00:00:00 but I want to display it like 2014-04-21.

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tblResults" Width="30%" OnItemDataBound="dgList_ItemCreated" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="dgList_Sort" ID="dgList" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:HyperLinkColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="loading" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="PublicHolidays.aspx?DateID={0}" DataNavigateUrlField="ID" DataTextField="BankHol" HeaderText="Bank Holidays" SortExpression="BankHol" ></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="Is Active" SortExpression="IsActive" Visible = "false" ></asp:BoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>
```

I know for BoundColumns I could use `DataTextFormatString` or `DataFormatString` but these can't be used in a HyperLinkColumn. It gives the error not a valid attribute for HyperLinkColumn. So can I edit the code behind the DataGrid and format the column to ToShortDateString like you can with a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

try instead of

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="loading" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="PublicHolidays.aspx?DateID={0}" DataNavigateUrlField="ID" DataTextField="BankHol" HeaderText="Bank Holidays" SortExpression="BankHol" ></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
```

this

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="loading" NavigateUrl='PublicHolidays.aspx?DateID=<%# Eval("YourDatetimeColumn").ToString().Substring(0, Eval("YourDatetimeColumn").ToString().IndexOf(" ")) %>' DataTextField="BankHol" HeaderText="Bank Holidays" SortExpression="BankHol" ></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Date is still showing as 2014-04-21 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

it looks like DataTextFormatString is valid:

see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.datatextformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Anyway, Eval method should have an overload in order to set custom format, e.g.

```
Eval("{0:MyDateField}", "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Regards,
Stefano